# google spreadsheetFeed count null

Tags: google-sheets, google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

I am working on google spreadsheet for inserting,creating and updating a spreadsheet by php.
I have include all library from
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client
and follow all steps.In which i am facing a problem in token.Actually my code is working properly and it is generating the access Token for accessing google Spreadsheets but when i have count the spreadsheet Feed

```
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
print_r(count($spreadsheetFeed));
```

It is showing me 0 result.I have read about it but i don't understand where is my fault.so anyone can help to solve it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you receive 0 results, make sure that you shared the sheets with the client email in order to get results. Also, make sure that the name of the sheets is correct.

Comment: Thanks Kendi,It is working now.I have shared the sheets with client email and it is working.

Comment: you can [accept or upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) my answer if it help you thanks